Bessel potential on Torus.
The potential Bessel operator $(I-\Delta)^{s/2}:H^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)\to L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is an isomorphism. Here, $(I-\Delta)u=\mathcal{F}^{-1}((1+|\xi|^2)^{s/2}\widehat{u})$ with Fourier transform in distribution sense, $H^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ Bessel space (crucial: Fourier transform is an isomorphism on tempered distribution space and any function in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is identified with a tempered distribution).
Question 1. On the torus: $(I-\Delta)^{s/2}:H^{s,p}(\mathbb{T}^n)\to L^p(\mathbb{T}^n)$ is analogously? Fourier transform is an isomorphism between periodic tempered distribution?
Question 2. Is $\mathcal{F}:D'(\mathbb{T}^n)\to S'(\mathbb{Z}^n)$ an isomorphism?
